# Gradient Descent for Primal Kernel SVM with Soft-Margin(Hinge) Loss

Tags: statistics, optimization, vector-spaces, machine-learning, subgradient

Given the primal objective
$$F({\bf a})=L\sum_{i,j}a_{i}a_{j}k(x_i,x_j) + \sum_{i}max(0, 1-y_i \sum_{j}a_jk(x_i,x_j)$$

for the soft margin SVM, where ${\bf a}=(a_1,...,a_N)$, N being the number of training examples.
I am trying to get the stochastic gradient descent update for $\textbf{a}$.

Details (could be considered or ignored :-):

I've been trying to read [Online Learning with Kernels](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips14/AA33.pdf). While it makes sense for the general case for a general $f$, I don't know how to adapt it here.

More specifically:
In the paper we have the general objective
$c(x_t, y_t, f(x_t)) + \frac{L}{2}||f||^2$. I understand that by taking the derivative with respect to f, we get to the update $f=(1-Lr)f - rc'(x_t,y_t,f(x_t))k(x_t,.)$.

Now in my case (soft margin/hinge loss kernel SVM) I don't really see how to apply that in order to get the updates for $a_i$. I mean, if I just go ahead and take the derivative of my initial $F({\bf a})$, I get 
$\frac{d}{da_i}F_n({\bf a})=2LGA - y_nk(x_n,x_i)\text{ right?}$ ($G$ being the gramm matrix) (I have considered the objective $F_n({\bf a})=L\sum_{i,j}a_{i}a_{j}k(x_i,x_j) + max(0, 1-y_n \sum_{j}a_jk(x_n,x_j))$.

But... now what?... :-) Thank you.